# Is there any way to pass variable A from button( onlick=xxx) to java or jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, jstl

I have a table with "confirm" button on the right column of each row.

```
<%List<Item> items= (List<Item>)request.getAttribute("items");
for(int i =0;i<items.size();i++){
    String name= items.get(i).getName();
    int price = items.get(i).getPrice();%>
   <div class="td"><%=name%></div>  
   <div class="td"><%=price%></div>  
   <div class="td"><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">confirm</button></div>    
<%}%>
```

When I click 'confirm', a floating window will pop up over the current page. I want to know which row I click

```
 <!--float window-->
   <div id="id01"> 
   <form>
   <div>
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

------here, I want to get items.get(i) object ,i is the row I click -----

  </div></form></div>
```

Is there any way to do this? thanks for any help

Comment: Do you realize Java runs on the server so there is no way to do it without another HTTP request? That is why we have form submissions and ajax/fetch requests.

Comment: From where are you getting this `id01`?

Comment: or instead of using this way, do you have any other ways to implement this pop-up window

Comment: You will probably have to resort to using javascript to do this.  You could write i into your loop, something like: `<button onclick="confirm(<%= i %>);" style="width:auto" etc...`